# Loadrunner does not record

Tags: testing, performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

While recording I get the below error:

**There is no Internet Access. You may be unable to record and execute the business process.This may affected you even actual business process does not require an Internet Connection. Since the selected browser my require Internet access.**

Has someone encountered this kind of problem before? when I call my call my **url** in the browser it works fine (IE,Firefox,Chrome), I don't know if something must be configured in the record setting...
HP Virtual User Geneartor Version : 12.50

Comment: It shwos me the recording bar only 1 time with firfox after rebooting my pc,

Comment: Has it ever recorded successfully on this PC?  If not then you likely have a failed installation or your credentials are insufficient for use or you have an intervening aggressive antivirus.

Comment: now i'm suprsied it does record, but the site has  a secure shell protocol,(https), and in the middle of the recoding, I get the "Error: Secure Connection Failed", and of course no code could be genearated in the action section...normally when I do it manually I give the crdentials,and then it worked fine,I don't why during the record it did not showed me the pop up window to give the  credential,instead I get  "Error: Secure Connection Failed"

Comment: Here is the couple of checkpoints:

1. Run VuGen as Administrator
2. Make sure the proxy is correct in the Internet Explorer settings
3. Go to Recording Settings, Click on Advanced under HTTP Properties, check the "Use the LoadRunner Proxy to record a local application" checkbox.

Comment: Check a control site, such as the sample flight reservation system on both local and remote hosts, to ensure that your system is operating properly independent of your application.  If it fails against the control application, which represents a known good, then this points to systemic failures in the installation or your environment configuration

Answer (score 1):

If your business process is completely internal (i.e. you only access intranet sites), you may ignore this message, there's a "don't show again" checkbox there. If your business process does require an internet access, and you're saying that you have such connection, you may still get this message every now and then. It may indicate a momentary disconnection or slowing down of your connection. Quite often, if you choose not to continue the recording after seeing the warning, and then press the "Record" button again, the warning disappears.
In any case, it's just a warning, you may ignore it and continue with recording. The real question is whether you're able to record or not.